Deleting custom metadata records and impact on existing records
Will there be any impact on existing data when custom metadata records are deleted?
We have custom metadata records for "codes" (abbreviations) that are used to generate campaign names along with some other fields using workflow. Now we would like to discontinue using the codes. What happens to existing campaign names that were generated in the past post deletion of metadata records/codes?

Nothing would happen. Those records are already saved, so it wouldn't cause any loss of data.
